# How to make uppercase math Greek letters italic by default with notomath?

Tags: fonts, noto

For Moodle illustrations I use the package `noto`. However, I would like the upper case Greek characters to be italic by default, as required by ISO 80000. Currently I can only do italics with the `\mathit` command.

Other packages I work with (`newtx`, `minionpro`) have corresponding options, but there is no information on this in the `noto` documentation. Basically, I want upper case Greek letters to behave the same as lower case Greek letters, being straigthened with `\up`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{notomath}

\begin{document}
$\alpha \upalpha \Phi \upPhi \mathit{\Phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`notomath` is based on `newtx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault,slantedGreek]{notomath}

\begin{document}

$\alpha \upalpha \Phi \upPhi \mathit{\Phi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, I knew that `notomath` was based on `newtx`, but it never occurred to me that passing the same parameter would solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`\up*` is for an upright (straight) character, not an uppercase character.

For example, capital alpha is A; capital beta is B; while the capital form of σ (`\sigma`) is Σ (`\Sigma`). Thus, not every Greek letter has a unique uppercase form. For a detailed list, please refer to the table in the following link: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/List_of_Greek_letters_and_math_symbols#Greek_letters.

For a consistent result, you may consider the `textgreek` package. In this case, `\textalpha` and `\textAlpha` will give you the desired result.

Comment: I know.  That was a lapsus linguae.  My bad.